# Check proof of recurrence for the number of ternary strings of length n that contain 00, 11, or 22

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, proof-verification, recurrence-relations

The question:

> Find a recurrence for the number of n length ternary strings that contain "00", "11", or "22".

My answer:

$3(a_{n-2}) + 3(a_{n-1} - 1)$

Proof:

Cases:

______________00  (a_(n-2))

______________11    (a_(n-2))

______________22  (a_(n-2))

______________0   (a_(n-1) - 1)

______________1   (a_(n-1) - 1)

______________2   (a_(n-1) - 1)    (Subtract the case in which it ends with 00, 11, or 22)

Comment: Since the mistake is addressed below, let us mention that admissible strings of length $n$ either start by an admissible string of length $n-1$, and then the last letter is free, or by an non admissible string of length $n-1$, and then the last letter must repeat the previous-to-last letter. Thus, the number $a_n$ of  admissible strings of length $n$ solves $a_1=0$ and, for every $n\geqslant1$, $$a_{n+1}=3a_n+(3^{n}-a_{n})$$ Considering the proportions of admissible strings $$p_n=\frac{a_n}{3^n}$$ one gets $p_1=0$ and $$p_{n+1}=\frac13+\frac23p_n$$ thus, $1-p_1=1$ and ...

Comment: $$1-p_{n+1}=\frac23\left(1-p_n\right)$$ hence $$p_n=1-\left(\frac23\right)^{n-1}$$ and finally, $$a_n=3^n-3\cdot2^{n-1}$$

Answer (score 3):

Let's see: $a_0 = 0$, $a_1 = 0$, $a_2 = 3$.  No, that's not $3 a_0 + 3 (a_1 - 1)$.

Comment: ahhh, can you think of an answer for this?

Comment: Shall $a_0$ be included in the sequence? It seems to be an exceptional case.

Comment: @DavidK That's not what I'm talking about. What I'm talking about is that $\{a_1,a_2,\ldots\}$ satisfies a somewhat simple recurrence relation that $a_0$ does not satisfy. So, while the OP's answer is indeed wrong, one should use $a_1,a_2,a_3$ to check his/her answer, not $a_0,a_1,a_2$ because $a_0$ is a pathological case. By the way, $a_3$ is 15, not 18.

Comment: @user1551 You caught my error. But OP's recurrence doesn't give $15$ either. :-)

Answer (score 3):

Your first mistake is this:
$$
\underline{\qquad\qquad}00 \quad (a_{n-2})
$$
You seem to be assuming that no string that ends in $00$ should be
counted unless it *also* contains $00$, $11$, or $22$ somewhere
earlier in the string.

For example, for $n=6$, you do not count the string $012100$,
because the first  four digits $0121$ are not among the $a_4$
strings of length $4$ that contain $00$, $11$, or $22$.